# No "Places", "Bookmarks", "Devices" labels in Naultilus sidebar

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

Asus X550C

Nautilus GNOME 3.14.3

---

I have no main labels in the sidebar.
How to fix that? I would like to have these separators.
I tried reinstalling Nautilus but that does not help.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Nautilus are you running? Find out with `nautilus --version` or in the *About* dialogue accessible from the main menu. The labels may have been scrapped during a redesign in a more recent version of Nautilus. You can try alternate file managers like [Nemo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nemo/) (the [captain of the *Nautilus*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Nemo)).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Oh, I forgot about adding this information to the post.  It's GNOME nautilus 3.14.3.  Yes, I heard of Nemo so I asked only to know whether there is an obvious solution or not. Hmm. Possibly, you are right about the new design. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the Gnome developers removed the section labels of Nautilus’ tree view pane during a re-design for the 3.14 release ([source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/ubuntu-16-04-reverts-to-older-version-of-nautilus)¹):

[image: Nautilus screenshot]

Knowing the Gnome developers, there is quite probably no way to change this through configuration or theming options.

---

However, you can try alternate file managers like

- [Nemo](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nemo/) (the [captain of the *Nautilus*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Nemo)), the default file manager of the Cinnamon Desktop and a fork of Nautilus.

---

¹ I know the file name is a bit misleading. The figure title on the source page says “Nautilus 3.14.3”, though.

Comment: Wow, you were really right about the re-design. I have installed Nemo and it's definetely great! Thank you.